# ¿Como puedo solucionar "Vue.component is not a function"?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hola a todos espero se encuentren bien, les cuento mi problema, estoy haciendo un proyecto en Laravel 8 con Laravel UI y estoy aprendiendo a usar vue para el lado del usuario el problema es que no puedo mostrar un simple "hola mundo", en la consola del navegador me aparece el siguiente error:

```
app.js:1919 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function
at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:1919)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:49597)
at checkDeferredModulesImpl (app.js:49735)
at Function.__webpack_require__.x (app.js:49748)
at app.js:49755
at app.js:49757
```

Lei varios post con este problema pero ninguno me ayudo a solucionarlo, mi app.js luce asi:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');
//window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue';

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hola Vue!'
      }

});
```

y mi package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^26.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

En la consola escribí un Vue.component y el resultado fue "undefined".

¿A qué se debe este error? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué tenés comentado `window.Vue = require('vue');`?

Comment: @padaleiana en un post lei a alguien que le funciono eso y lo reemplace por "import Vue from 'vue';", pero nada :(

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu package.json?

Comment: @oswaldog claro, lo añadí al post

Comment: @BetaM Entiendo, intente dejarlo, realice el run dev y nada :/.

Comment: cambiar la version de laravel mix a la 5

Comment: ¿Qué sucede si colocás `window.Vue = Vue;` luego del import de vue?

Comment: @padaleiana Lo intente y no funciono.

Comment: @padaleiana hice lo que me dijiste y actualice composer y comenzó a funcionar :). Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

añadí el import de Vue, luego, abajo del import definí el window.Vue = require('vue'): El código quedó así

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');


import Vue from 'vue';

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hola Vue!'
      }

});
```

y actualize la version de mi composer, y comenzó a funcionar :). Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: ¡Recuerda [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta!